# Requesting Data From HealthKit on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit

I have a watch kit app that tries to request HealthKit permission from the interface controller on Apple watch, however when I run the app I am never asked for permission and the app defaults to not having health kit permission. How can I make the apple request HealthKit permission ?

Comment: Do it through the app. Also, once it has been granted or canceled, the app will not ask for it any more. Delete the app and try again.

Comment: Yes I know it will only request once. The problem I run into is that I need the health store in the interface controller to be used on the watch. How do I request permission on the app but still retain the HKHealth store on the watch ?

Comment: You should manage the HealthKit stuff in the app and pass the necessary data to the watch independent from the HealthKit framework.

Comment: @Mundi WatchKit apps can access HealthKit data on watchOS 2. Why do you suggest that the only use HealthKit on the phone?

Comment: @loadedjd it would be helpful if you posted the snippets of code from your watch and phone apps that are attempting requesting authorization. Perhaps they have a bug or your are missing a step.

Comment: @Allan I know, but it is preferable to keep the Watch code as slim as possible. Also, handling permission requests on the Watch is not a very pleasant UX. I would not do this just because it is possible.

Answer (score 16):

You can request health kit access from your watchOS app, but the user will need to accept the request on their iPhone. To do this, you request access to health kit on your watchOS app like normal:

```
var healthKitTypesToRead = Set<HKObjectType>()
// TODO: add your read types here

var healthKitTypesToWrite = Set<HKSampleType>()
// TODO: add your write types here

healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
    // TODO: Handle success or failure
}
```

And then you need to add this to your AppDelegate in your iOS app:

```
func applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    healthStore.handleAuthorizationForExtensionWithCompletion { (success, error) -> Void in
        //...
    }
}
```

Now when you request health kit permissions from the user on the watch, they will get a permission dialog on the watch telling them to accept or deny permissions on their iPhone. When they go to their iPhone, your app's health kit permission dialog will be waiting. Once they have set their preferences on the iPhone, your requestAuthorizationToShareTypes completion handler will be called on your apple watch.

Comment: applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization was the tipp that helped me.
@loadedjd: why not accept this answer as the right one?